# How to dismiss Google account chooser screen in my android app when my app goes to background and then comes back

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, google-signin, accountpicker

I have implemented Google sign-in in my application. When I tap the sign in with google button my screen is as the screenshot displayed below. Lists all accounts signed in my phone.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZOkY.png)

Then I press my Home button and my app goes to background. After that when I select my app from background the same screen exists like in the screenshot. I want to dismiss this account chooser screen whenever i goes to background and then comes back. I want my Home activity screen to be displayed when I goes to background and comes back. Whats the solution for this friends?

**EDITED** :  This is how the account picker is started  ..

```
private void signInWithGoogle() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

and the callback of this intent is received in

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

**Edited 2**
This is how I call the signInWithGoogle() method

```
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.signInWithGoogleBtn:
                isGsigninInProgress = true;
                signInWithGoogle();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you call `signInWithGoogle()`.

Comment: Updated in Edit 2 @Kevin..

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    if(google_picker.isShowing(){
        google_picker.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Whenever the app is resumed this will close your picker if it is open

Comment: The Google sign-in dialog is what I'm referring to when I say google_picker.
At some point you have _variablename_.show() so the way to dismiss that same dialog is _variablename_.dismiss

Comment: No @MacLean. No variables are used for account picker. Only an Intent is started.            `Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);`  And its result (also control) will be got back inside `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`. So what to do?

Comment: You should edit your question and post all of the relevant code there to make it readable